# Как оформить часто встречающиеся функций?

Tags: android, java

Приветствую всех!
В проекте есть несколько классов в java файлах. Есть некоторый набор функций, которые необходимо использовать везде. Это вроде проверки, есть ли интернет соединение, есть ли SD-карта. Как лучше оформить и использовать их, чтобы не описывать в каждом классе?
Спасибо

Comment: омг... т.е ооп... =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В java нет функций. Просто нет. Но есть их эквивалент - статические методы. Некоторые "гуру" могут и не понять, если будете говорить о функциях в java.

А решение Вашей задачи известно и оно очень простое. Сделайте себе отдельный класс, который обычно имеет название Utils и добавляйте туда все необходимые "функции" как публичные статические методы. Ну где то так

```
public class Utils {
  public static boolean isSDCadrdExists() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

а потом просто вызывайте по необходимости

```
if (Utils.isSDCardExists()) {
  // do 
}
```

Когда методов в этом классе станет много, разделяйте на два (или три) и делайте классы UtilsNetwork, UtilsMath, CommonUtils (или как по функционалу будет адекватнее).

Этот метод очень популярен в java. Как пример реализации, можно посмотреть на класс Math.

Comment: Спасибо, как раз закончил писать такой класс, забыл static указать, думал, почему же не работает)

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов развития событий такой: оформляете базовую активити абстрактной и в нее помещаете protected-методы определения наличия сетевого подключения, sd карты и т.д. Потом каждую активити наследуете от этой абстрактной и просто вызываете эти метода в нужных местах.
А вообще это вопрос больше по ООП и ООД, андроид не налаживает каких-то архитектурных ограничений на ваш код. Применяйте нормальные практики ООП, дженерики, паттерны проектирования не стесняясь

Comment: Да, но функции используются не только в активиностях. 
О множественном наследовании, как я понял в java и речи нет.
А если для удобства создать отдельный класс и в нем описать все функции, потом создавать его экземпляр в каждом классе и вызывать необходимые методы?

Comment: так и надо сделать

Comment: и пожалуйста, забудьте слово "функция" в java, там методы.